# error: null value in column "text" violates not-null constraint. I have put field required in HTML, but what more do I need to do for stopping this?

Tags: javascript, postgresql

Sorry for bad English - I am working on it.

I am wondering what should be done to avoid the server stopping in such a case?  I have input field into which to enter some text.  The input field has required on it.

```
    .todo-form
        form
            .form-group
                input.form-control.input-lg(type='text', placeholder='Enter text...', ng-model='formData.text', required='')
            button.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg.btn-block(type='submit', ng-click='createTodo()') Add Todo
```

And here is the code to create todo:

```
// Create a new todo
    $scope.createTodo = function(todoID) {
        $http.post('/api/v1/todos', $scope.formData)
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.formData = {};
                $scope.todoData = data;
                console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function(error) {
                console.log('Error: ' + error);
            });
    };
```

Is it here that I will have to be having a condition, `if the length is 0`, then I will make `$scope.inputError = "Please enter a valid texts"`, else do

```
$http.post('/api/v1/todos', $scope.formData)
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.formData = {};
                $scope.todoData = data;
                console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function(error) {
                console.log('Error: ' + error);
            });
    };
```

I appreciate kindly the response.  Thank you.

I have made following change to the create the todo, thanks to comment from Mr  winhowes:

```
// Create a new todo
    $scope.createTodo = function(todoID) {

        //console.log(($scope.formData.text).length);

        if ((($scope.formData.text).length) == 0) {
            console.log("length 0");
        }

        else {  

                $http.post('/api/v1/todos', $scope.formData)
                    .success(function(data) {
                        $scope.formData = {};
                        $scope.todoData = data;
                        console.log(data);
                    })
                    .error(function(error) {
                        console.log('Error: ' + error);
                    });
            }
    };
```

Comment: Add that check before you make the ajax request

Comment: thank you Sir, I will do the needful and revert back the results.

Comment: Sir thank you I have done the needful